# Simple Way to Read Integers from a File

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I am trying to read in a file which is essentially a list of integers, seperated by a line. Obviously, file input can never be trusted so I need to filter out non-integers.

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

I know the `as` operator usually converts if it can and then assigns a null, however because `int` isn't nullable this isn't the case. I thought that perhaps I could cast to `Nullable<int>`. I have never really delved into this, I thought perhaps I could do:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("");
var numbers = lines.Select(line => line as int?).Where(i => i != null);
```

I know that I could get potentially get around this by doing:

```
var numbers = lines.Select(line =>
                                  {
                                    int iReturn = 0;
                                    if (int.TryParse(line, out iReturn ))
                                      return iReturn;
                                    else
                                      return null;        
                                  }).Where(i => i != null);
```

I also could potentially do it as an extension method.

I was just looking for a neat, concise way of doing the cast in a statement and also understanding why my code is invalid.

Comment: Nope. C# is deliberately cautious about this sort of thing.

Comment: @ColonelPanic it probably is, but why if I you are handling the fact that it could potentially be null is this not aloud? What is the difference between this and casting `Foo object` `as` `Bar object`?

Comment: Additionally, if one is protectting against malicious input the File.ReadAllLines(...) call should be replaced by an enumerator (or equivalent functionality) that reads lines and validates them sequentially, and limits their length.

Comment: I edited the title because the question got good answers - which did not answer the original question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm always using this simple extension method:

```
public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Then it's easy:

```
 var numbers = lines.Select(line => line.TryGetInt())
                    .Where(i => i.HasValue)
                    .Select(i => i.Value);
```

You can also use `int.TryParse` without the extension, but that is undocumented hence might stop working in future:

```
int i = 0;
var numbers = lines.Where(line => int.TryParse(line, out i))
                   .Select(line => i);
```

**Edit**

> "also understanding why my code is invalid"

relevant code:

```
if (int.TryParse(line, out iReturn ))
  return iReturn;
else
  return null;
```

It would work if you'd replace

```
else
    return null;
```

with

```
else
    return (int?)null;
```

because you are returning an `int`, but `null` is not convertible implicitly to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a concise way to do this because here you don't need to cast (you *cannot* cast) -- you need to convert from one type to another. The types of course are `int` and `string` (so not exactly "any" types), but as in the general case any conversion between unrelated types cannot be done "just like that".

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Your terminology is wrong, so you should double-check your facts. `foo as Bar` is not boxing; boxing is what happens when you put value types into an `object`. `string` cannot be *forced* to any type -- what is "forced" supposed to mean?

Comment: @LukeHennerley: In general, casts that don't box/unbox do not change *anything* at runtime. What they change is the bookkeeping information the compiler has during compilation.

Comment: Sorry haha, haven't used this terminology since my training :P But thanks for clearing this up for me, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. C# is deliberately cautious about changing strings to numbers.

You can make your code shorter (no more nulls) using a foreach loop

```
var numbers = new List<int>();

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    int n;
    if (int.TryParse(line, out n))
        numbers.Add(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and extension method

```
public static int? ToInt(this string s, int default){  ... }
```

and use it in LINQ:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path); 
var numbers = lines.Select(line => line.ToInt())
                   .Where(i => i != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and you want just filter the non integer lines, maybe regex is an option?

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("");
var numbers = lines.Where(i => Regex.IsMatch(i, "[0-9]+"));
```

Comment: I want to filter yes but I want to return `int[]`, obviously `var` isn't a clear indication of this - sorry.

Comment: The question is related to the casting though, so although this could pre-filter what would the answer to the actual question be?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I came up with:

Use this extension method:

```
public static class Int32Extensions
    {
        public static int? ParseOrDefault(this string text)
        {
            int iReturn = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(text, out iReturn))
            {
                return iReturn;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Like this:

```
var query = lines.Select(x => x.ParseOrDefault()).Where(x => x.HasValue);
```